# Car losing speed on hills

Tags: vw, automatic-transmission, jetta

I have a 2012 Volkswagen Jetta sitting at around 124,000 miles. I recently was driving from St. Louis to Pittsburgh at my car would not accelerate properly and at around 70mph, if the rpm hit 4000, my car would immediately lose speed and I could hear that the engine was not making any sound almost like it was parked. If I tried to accelerate while this was happening my rpm meter (I don't know the actual name of it) would start jumping around and I wouldn't gain any speed. I would have to tap my brakes and then gently accelerate. Almost like I was pressing the break to switch gears but I have an automatic transmission. I did stop when my check engine light came on and had someone take a look at the code but he said the code had already been moved to history and the issue most likely resolved itself, I was exhausted and let him clear the light and forgot to ask for the code just in case. Any ideas? I am thinking transmission issues but really hoping it isn't.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is going to be hard to diagnose over the internet without more information. The code would have been a big help, but water under the bridge. Is your Jetta diesel or gasoline? Was it *every time* your Jetta hit 70mph and you tried to accelerate this problem occurred (ie: is it repeatable)? Was this happening with cruise control on?

Comment: My jetta is gasoline and it was not every time I hit 70. If I was going 70 on a hill, it almost always happened. It did occur with cruise control on, if I did not have cruise control on, my car would not accelerate up the hill but the engine would cut out if I tried to accelerate up the hill. My check engine light came back on, here are the codes that came up this time: P0527 Fan Speed Sensor Circuit Range/ Performance and P0327 Knock Sensor 1 Circuit Low Bank1 or Single Sensor